# Named query with inheritance entities ignore setFirstResult/setMaxResults

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I use inheritance for JPA entities (RegisteredAction etc).

```
public class Feed {
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "ACTION_ID", nullable = false)
    private Action action;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "USER_ID", nullable = false)
    private User user;  
    ...
}


public abstract class Action {
    @Id
    private Integer id;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private FanoutType fanout;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private ActionType type;
    ...
}


public class RegisteredAction extends Action {
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "USER_ID", nullable = false)
    private User user;

    ...
}
```

Do a named query to the database:

```
select a from Feed as f join f.action as a where f.user.id = :userId order by f.creationDate desc
```

All is well, Hibernate loads the information about entities. But if I want to add setFirstResult/setMaxResults methods, nothing changes:

```
getEntityManager().createNamedQuery(Feed.FEED_BY_USER, Action.class)
            .setParameter(USER_ID, userId)
            .setHint(QueryHints.READ_ONLY, true)
            .setFirstResult(offset)
            .setMaxResults(count)
            .getResultList();
```

Hibernate ignores these settings and return all rows.

Comment: So the code you're having trouble with you do not actually post...

Comment: Which database are you using, maybe it's a bug in the hibernate database dialect driver?

Comment: MySQL 5.6 and Hibernate 4.2.7. Try to trace bug in debug...

Comment: did you get any explanation?